# ion-infinite-scroll loops forever calling on-infinite callback

Tags: ionic-framework, infinite-scroll, ion-infinite-scroll

The problem: If I exit the current `ion-view` when the `on-finite` callback hasn't finished processing, the `on-infinite` callback will start getting called in a loop until the app freezes, even if I'm not in the view anymore where the `ion-infinite-scroll` was installed.

This was difficult to reproduce, but I have found a way to easily manifest it. Setup the on-infinite callback on the view.

```
<ion-infinite-scroll
    immediate-check="false"
    on-infinite="loadMore()"
    distance="5%">
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

And then use `$timeout` to artificially slow down the `loadMore()` function to 2 seconds. Something like this:

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {
    console.log("Loading more...");
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    }, 2000);
};
```

Now, trigger the infinite scroll, and while your `loadMore()` function is "processing" for 2 seconds, leave your view. You will see that even that you are in another view, the console will continue to print "Loading more..." every 2 seconds. That is, `loadMore()` is being called in a loop.

On a real scenario, this bug is causing the app to freeze badly. On some links this issue has been addressed but no solutions (the ionic forum is down atm, btw). Some solutions out there suggest calling `infiniteScrollComplete` inside an `$apply()`, but that doesn't solve it and actually triggers a `digest already in progress` error. Others suggest to use `$timeout(...,0)` as an alternative to `$apply()` but still the issue will manifest if, for instance, your `loadMore()` does async calls to your server, in such case there is still a chance that the user exits the view while `loadMore()` is busy.

Is there any suggested workaround to this?

Ionic team: this is a bug. And all documentation everywhere about ion-infinite-scroll completely ignores this. There should be, at the very least, a warning. My ionic version 1.7.16.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for stop load more callback.

### html

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
    <ion-content>
        <h1>Search</h1>
        <ion-infinite-scroll
        immediate-check="false"
        ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable"
        on-infinite="loadMore()"
        distance="5%">
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

### Controller

```
$scope.loadMore = function()
{
    $http({
    method:'GET',
    url:'http://headers.jsontest.com/'
    }).then(function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
    }, function(response)
    {});
}
```

Comment: Well, in the context of your code, I don't want to set noMoreItemsAvailable to true only when I have really finished loading pages. Also, you don't specify where broadcast infiniteScrollComplete. I don't think you understood the issue. It appears when you exit the view and loadMore() is busy. The app will start calling loadMore() in a loop, even when you are not in the same view where infinite scroll was installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for infinite loop functionality

**HTML**

```
    <ion-infinite-scroll 
        ng-if="!noMoreDaTa" on-infinite="loadData()" 
        distance="2%" immediate-check="false">
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

**Controller**

```
    $scope.loadData = function() {
       if ($scope.dataRecords.length >= $scope.total_records) {
           $scope.noMoreDaTa = true;
       }
    }
```

Please let me know, if you need any help :)